# Why the function checkAB doesn't work properly?

Tags: java

first thing first, I want to explain what the function sod1 does so the rest will be easier to understand. it gets a list and a char, and it checks if the char exists in the list and if it does then it returns the char. Problem comes in the next function. I want the function sod2 to check if the next char of a is b or if the next char of b is a. Do you guys can see the problem?

public class MainClass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Node<Character> n1 = new Node<Character>('b');
    Node<Character> n2 = new Node<Character>('a');
    Node<Character> n3 = new Node<Character>('s');
    Node<Character> n4 = new Node<Character>('h');

    n1.setNext(n2);
    n2.setNext(n3);
    n3.setNext(n4);

    System.out.println(checkAB(n1));

}//Main



public static Node<Character> sod1(Node<Character> lst, char ch){
    if(lst == null) return null;
    if(lst.getValue() == ch) return lst;
    return sod1(lst.getNext(), ch);
}

public static boolean checkAB(Node<Character> lst) {
    if(sod1(lst,'a').getNext().equals('b') || sod1(lst, 'b').getNext().equals('a'))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

}//Class

Answer (score 0):

getNext() will return Node< Character>, you shouldnt compare it with a string.

Compare it by calling getValue() function or with another Node< Character> having value 'a' or 'b'